# Bash: Replace semicolon outside the quote with all pattern

Tags: bash

I have generate PSQL file from Excel with python
to run psql in bash script.

I would like to replace specific semicolon like this

> SELECT *; FROM table ;WHERE description =';'**;**
>
> SELECT *; FROM table ;WHERE description like '%;%'**;**

THE Result should except semicolon in all type of quote/double quotes like this

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE description =';'
>
> SELECT * FROM table WHERE description like '%;%'

Comment: `sed 's/;$//g' file`

Comment: What if there's more than one semicolon like this ?
select * from 1 where 1=';';
select ;* from 1 where 1=';';;;

Comment: Please post a new question with clear details: 1. your input file 2. your expected output 3. Your attempt to solve the issue.